# Disable drag&drop in solution explorer using VS 2015

Tags: drag-and-drop, visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

Is there any way in VS2015 Community version to disable accidental Drag&Drop in Solution Explorer?

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO. Anyway, [VSCommands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionExplorer) used to provide this feature for other VS versions. Their VS2015 version doesn't seem to be finished anytime soon, but eventually you might get it.